# Detect HTTP response using automation instruments in Xcode

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I am using the automation instruments in Xcode. I would like to check the response I get when I use a HTTP connection. I don't know if this is possible.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)readMe
{
    [HTTPConnection sendGetToUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:READ_ME_URL]
                          target:self
                        selector:@selector(readMeFinished:responseCode:)
                    failSelector:@selector(downloadFailed:)
                        userInfo:nil];
}

- (void)readMeFinished:(NSData *)recievedData
          responseCode:(NSString *)responseCode
{
    //If the response is a 200 OK.
    if ([responseCode isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        // HERE, I WOULD LIKE TO DETECT IN AUTOMATION 
        // THAT I'VE RECEIVED A 200 AND PASS THE TEST
    }
}

- (void)downloadFailed:(HTTPConnection *)connection {
    // HERE, I WOULD LIKE TO DETECT IN AUTOMATION THAT 
    // THE DOWNLOAD HAS FAILED AND DON'T PASS THE TEST
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The automation instrument has no way to reach into your Objective-C code and check for results. It's only access to your application's state is through the user interface.

So, to detect if you have a HTTP 200 status code, you could expose that fact somehow with an invisible label. That would be a brute force way to expose inner application state to the automation instrument.

*However!...*

I would recommend instead testing for what the user sees if the network connection completes successfully. That's the best way to think about how to use the automation instrument. It's an integration testing tool focused on testing what the user sees and experiences by looking for the state of controls and text on the screen.

You don't provide enough context about what your code actually does in the app, but assuming that the method `-readMe` shows something to the user that they have to read and approve by clicking a button, I would check to for the result after telling the automation to click the button like a user. What does the user see if there isn't a 200 status code? Do they see an error message? Then to assert that the network code succeeded, check to make sure there isn't an alert window with that error message.

Comment: You are right, but my problem is... "When I get the 200?". I mean, the -readMe method is an asynchronous call, so I don't know when I am going to get the response code. That method fills some textFields with the user data that I receive in the response. I know that I could check if everything is OK if the textFields are filled, but I don't know when to check it, because I don't know when I am going to get the response. Well...I think I am going to add a delay or something like that to wait 4 or 5 seconds to get the response and then check the fields. Thanks!

Comment: The waiting is built in to UI Automation. Check out the `pushTimeout()` and `popTimeout()` methods on `UIATarget`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html

Answer (score 0):

For test automation purposes I think your solution would be better off as a Unit test versus using UI Automation. UI Automation is better used when you have a test case that involves navigating around your application and checking the flow and that expected UI elements are appearing and displaying properly.

If you prefer to stick to UIAutomation, I would recommend maybe creating a function that checks the fields .value() to be not equal to whatever they were initiated as, you can throw this into a while loop with a UIATarget.delay(x) that way you're only checking ever X seconds. I suggest this because then you can add the conditional of if the fields aren't filled then you can throw an error message in your automation test.